# How to invoke test after 1 hour in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have an case where 3rd party data updates in every 1 hours and i want verify those latest data in test using spring boot test but i unable to find the way to do this. anyone please help in this
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is a special case, so i would just use a timer like any other java code. Cna use spring. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks & https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Comment: thisis more an an integration test and not a unit test. but u can also use the Junit/ sprint testing framework along with timer. so you can get the usual reports. or make a seperate suite of integration tests see https://www.google.com/search?q=integration+testing+vs+unit+testing